# Assume v and V are harmonic conjugates of domain$\Omega$. Show that v(x,y)-V(x,y)=constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I believe that for v and V to be harmonic conjugates of u, both their first derivatives must satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations.  Hence $v_{y}=u_{x}=V_{y}$ and $u_{y}=-v_{x}=-V_{x}$.  Is this relationship correct?  From here how would i return to v and V form?  Do I integrate somehow?  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Since $v$ and $V$ are harmonic conjugates, *Cauchy-Riemann* equations holds for both $u$ and $v$ and $u$ and $V$, thus \begin{align}
v_x&=V_x,\ v_y=V_y. \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{align} 
Integrate the left side of (1) with respect  to $x$ to obtain the expression
\begin{equation}
v(x,y)=V(x,y)+\phi(y),
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is a real valued function of $y$. Derivate this with respect to $y$, then
\begin{equation}
v_y=V_y+\phi'(y). \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{equation}
You can conclude from (1) that $$\phi'(y)=0,$$ therefore $\phi(y)=C$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $C$ a real constant. From $(2)$ it follows that $$v(x,y)=V(x,y)+C.$$